# how to get a byte array or readable stream from a GZipStream

Tags: c#, stream, gzipstream

I would like to write a compressed version of a byte array to a SQL Server varbinary(max) column.

I would like to feed the parameter of the SqlClient's command a `SqlBytes` type, and have tried to instantiate that type so:

```
// data is a byte array at this point
SqlParameter p7 = new SqlParameter("@bytes", Compress(data));
p7.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarBinary;


public static SqlBytes Compress(byte[] input)
{

    using (MemoryStream memstream = new MemoryStream(input))
    {    
        using (GZipStream zipped = new GZipStream(memstream, CompressionMode.Compress))
        {               
            return new SqlBytes(zipped);    
        }    
    }
}
```

but the command fails with a "This operation is not supported" error (see trace below).  So I need to get the compressed content out of the GZipStream and into a form that would allow instantiation of a `SqlBytes` type.  How is that done?

NOTE: The GZipStream does not support reading, and so `zipped.CopyTo( myOuputMemoryStream)` will not work.

```
at System.IO.Compression.GZipStream.get_Length()
at System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlBytes.get_Value()
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.BinarySize(Object value, Boolean isSqlType)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.GetActualSize()
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.ValidateTypeLengths(Boolean yukonOrNewer)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.SetUpRPCParameters(_SqlRPC rpc, Int32 startCount, Boolean inSchema, SqlParameterCollection parameters)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.BuildRPC(Boolean inSchema, SqlParameterCollection parameters, _SqlRPC& rpc)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
at .Form1.Save2Database(Byte[] data) 

in c:\\Users\\foo\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\Test\\Test\\Form1.cs:line 228
```

Answer (score 2):

The stream you pass into the GZipStream constructor is the stream the data is written to in a compressed (or decompressed) format. You should create an empty memory stream and write your bytes to it using the GZipStream:

```
public static SqlBytes Compress(byte[] input)
{

    using (MemoryStream memstream = new MemoryStream())
    {    
        using (GZipStream zipped = new GZipStream(memstream, CompressionMode.Compress))
        {               
            zipped.Write(input, 0, input.Length);
        }   

        return new SqlBytes(memstream);             
    }
}
```